# Terminology of standard error and standard deviation of the mean. What to use?

Tags: statistics, terminology

I have found that for this equation
[image: eqn]
(sigma is the standard deviation) there exist two different terminologies, and  I don't know if there is a correct one or if they actually mean something different.

Wikipedia calls this the "standard error" or the "standard error of the mean" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error), some python packages also use this terminology (Pandas, Seaborn etc.).
The GUM calls it the "experimental standard deviation of the mean" (https://www.iso.org/sites/JCGM/GUM/JCGM100/C045315e-html/C045315e.html?csnumber=50461 Chapter B.2.17 Note 2) and even goes so far to say it is NOT the standard error of the mean.

I calculated my error bars with seaborns standard error ("se") option (https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/error_bars.html).
What should I call this? Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: I think the distinction the GUM publication is trying to make may be what is referred to in Section 3 Basic Concepts 3.2.2. They draw a distinction between "error" (strictly random error), a quantity inherent to the system, and "uncertainty", a quantity associated with our knowledge of the system.

Comment: If the population distribution has finite expectation $\mu$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$, then the mean of an iid sample is a random variable $\bar{X}$  with expectation $\mu$ and variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$.  So it can be an estimator of $\mu$ and its standard deviation  is $\sqrt{\mathbb E[(\bar X -\mu)^2]} = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2}}$ and this is called the *"standard error of the mean"* as a root-mean-square measurement of the error $\bar X -\mu$.   Some people try to change the wording to make some of this more explicit.

Comment: @Henry thanks for the thorough explanation. So "standard error of the mean" is the standard terminology for this measure?

Comment: $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ is indeed usually called the "standard error of the mean" when taking a iid sample size $n$.  But usually you do not know $\sigma$, so estimate the standard error of the mean with something like $\frac{\sum(X_i-\bar X)^2}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}$, for which some people use the same or different name.  Or you may want a standard error for other sample statistics.